# Python fitz insert russian text in PDF not work

Tags: python, pdf, cyrillic, pymupdf

I tried insert russian text in PDF file and I see [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4lS6.png),
what am I doing wrong?

```
import fitz

if __name__ == '__main__':
    src_pdf_filename = 'original.pdf'
    dst_pdf_filename = 'destination.pdf'

    document = fitz.open(src_pdf_filename)
    
    ss = u"ToUnicode Привет Hello"
    
    for page in document:    
       
        page.insert_text((50, 250), ss, fontname="Times-Roman", fontsize=50,encoding=fitz.TEXT_ENCODING_CYRILLIC, overlay=False)

    document.save(dst_pdf_filename)

    document.close()
```

Comment: Using PyMuPDF for non-Latin text in this way is not the best option, because here only the non-ASCII part of the character codes <= 256 are influenced by the encodings option.
Full Cyrillic support must use a font that contains more than just 26 characters - see my example below (give me 5 minutes please).

Comment: (Tangentially, code you put in `if __name__ == '__main__':` should be trivial; the purpose of this boilerplate is to allow you to import the code, which you will not want to do anyway if the logic you need is not available via import. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778466/874188)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of writing text uses no embedded (file-based) font and is therefore limited.

```py
import fitz
doc=fitz.open()
page=doc.new_page()
font=fitz.Font("tiro")  # this is a full font file
page.insert_font(fontname="F0", fontbuffer=font.buffer)
page.insert_text((50, 250), "ToUnicode Привет Hello", fontname="F0", fontsize=50, overlay=False)
doc.save("test.pdf")
```

Gives you this:
[image]

Comment: We have updated the documentation in this way - and no longer recommend non-embedded fonts where an extended Latin character (non-ASCII) set is required.